# Image resize PHP

Tags: php, image-resizing

Im trying to create a simple image resize feature, can you tell me where i'm going wrong:

```
//resize image 
  $imageSrc = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://www.katsmurals.com/cms/'.$target_path);
  $width = imagesx($imageSrc);
  $height = imagesy($imageSrc);
  echo $width;
  echo $height;
   //new dimensions
   $i = $width;
   $j = $height;
   while($i > 700){
    $i = $i / 1.5;
    $j = $j / 1.5;
   }

  $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($i, $j);
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://www.katsmurals.com/cms/'.$target_path);
  imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $i, $j, $width, $height);
  $newImage = $target_path.'_scaled.jpg';
  imagejpeg($image_p, $newImage, 80);
```

$target_path is the newly uploaded image, i want to resize it if the width is over 700.

Once this is done, a DB is updated with the information, at the moment the image is being uploaded fine, but the size seems to be exactly the same, so the resizing code isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resize image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

First argument of `imagecopyresampled` is resource (image), not string containing file name.

Comment: I have changed the code, still nothing, can you see where im going wrong?

Comment: @user please do some debugging. What are `width` and `height` values? What kind of image are you resizing? What format?

Comment: .jpg file, when echo'ing out width and height these are the results:
width:1235
height:1551

the while loop is successfully running to give new values, creating the new resized image is the problem.

Comment: I managed to get it woking, i have posted the code up for ayone who may need it in the future

Answer (score 1):

A very helpful and amazing code:

```
   <?php
    class SimpleImage {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {

  $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
  $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
  if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

     $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
  } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
  } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
  }
   }
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75,      $permissions=null) {

  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     imagegif($this->image,$filename);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     imagepng($this->image,$filename);
  }
  if( $permissions != null) {

     chmod($filename,$permissions);
  }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     imagejpeg($this->image);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     imagegif($this->image);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     imagepng($this->image);
  }
   }
   function getWidth() {

  return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {

  return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {

  $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
  $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
  $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resizeToWidth($width) {
  $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
  $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
  $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function scale($scale) {
  $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
  $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
  $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resize($width,$height) {
  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
  $this->image = $new_image;
   }      

}
?>
```

Link: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php
i found it very helpful.hope good for you.
Happy coding!!