# Resize image in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, image-resizing, image-upload

I want to write some PHP code that automatically resizes any image uploaded via a form to 147x147px, but I have no idea how to go about it (I'm a relative PHP novice).

So far, I've got images uploading successfully, filetypes being recognized and names cleaned up, but I'd like to add the resize functionality into the code. For example, I've got a test image that is 2.3MB, and 1331x1331 in dimension, and I'd like the code to size it down, which I'm guessing will dramatically compress the file size of the image, too.

So far, I've got the following:

```
if ($_FILES) {
    //Put file properties into variables
    $file_name = $_FILES['profile-image']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['profile-image']['size'];
    $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['profile-image']['tmp_name'];
    
    //Determine filetype
    switch ($_FILES['profile-image']['type']) {
        case 'image/jpeg': $ext = "jpg"; break;
        case 'image/png': $ext = "png"; break;
        default: $ext = ''; break;
    }
    
    if ($ext) {
        //Check filesize
        if ($file_size < 500000) {
            //Process file - clean up filename and move to safe location
            $n = "$file_name";
            $n = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.]", "", $n);
            $n = strtolower($n);
            $n = "avatars/$n";
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $n);
        } else {
            $bad_message = "Please ensure your chosen file is less than 5MB.";
        }
    } else {
        $bad_message = "Please ensure your image is of filetype .jpg or.png.";
    }
}

$query = "INSERT INTO users (image) VALUES ('$n')";
mysql_query($query) or die("Insert failed. " . mysql_error() . "<br />" . $query);
```

Comment: Have you tried samples likes these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029838/image-resize-with-php ?

Comment: without changing the `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`,firstly is it possible to upload the file of size more than `upload_max_filesize`?. Is there any chance to resize the image of size more than `upload_max_filesize`? without changing `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 181):

You need to use either PHP's [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) or [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) functions to work with images.

With GD, for example, it's as simple as...

```
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    return $dst;
}
```

And you could call this function, like so...

```
$img = resize_image(‘/path/to/some/image.jpg’, 200, 200);
```

From personal experience, GD's image resampling does dramatically reduce file size too, especially when resampling raw digital camera images.

Comment: Thanks! Forgive my ignorance, but where would that sit in the code that I've already got, and where would the function call sit? Am I right in saying that where I've got my database INSERT, rather than inserting $n, I'd insert $img? Or would $n be structured $n = ($img = resize_image(‘/path/to/some/image.jpg’, 200, 200));?

Comment: Are you storing images as `BLOB`s? I would recommend storing images in the filesystem and insert references in your database. I also recommend reading the full GD (or ImageMagick) documentation to see what other options you have available.

Comment: Blobs? The images are just being uploaded, names cleaned and then moved to a folder called avatars, before being called from there using a standard PHP echo.

Comment: Note, this solution only works for JPEGs. You can replace imagecreatefromjpeg with any of the following: imagecreatefromgd, imagecreatefromgif, imagecreatefrompng, imagecreatefromstring, imagecreatefromwbmp, imagecreatefromxbm, imagecreatefromxpm to deal with different image types.

Comment: @GordonFreeman Thanks for the great code snippet, but there is one glitch there, add `abs()`, like `ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)))` and same to the height part. It is needed for some cases.

Comment: S'pose, but I just run these examples off of the top o' me 'ead, don't I? Is there a PHPfiddle yet..? Well... I guess there is! :)

Comment: the script doesn't work, the image doesn't get created.

Comment: will the images get blur?In my case..I have images in random sizes(some 150 x 100,300 x 400,435 x305).I want two standard size 100x100 and 650x305.Will the images get blur?

Comment: @JayeshJain Yes! If you resize a small image to a bigger resolution it will lose details unlike the opposite, but be careful! your image if resized with another *height / width ratio* will be stretched

Comment: I think there is a problem with this script.  Specifically when resizing a portrait image with landscape sizes.  If I'm not mistaken, the problem is on this line: $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));  I think it the last part is supposed to be $h/$w

Comment: Changing the default crop value to true, and resizing the image at `http://wallpapercave.com/wp/wc1701171.jpg` to 400x128 (banner) created a black image; I can't figure out why it's doing that though.

Comment: This code doesn't work, if the src ratio - dest ratio more than 1

Comment: To save the resized image in the file system add `imagejpeg($dst, $file);` after the `imagecopyresampled($dst,...` line. Change `$file` if you don't want to overwrite the original.

Comment: Could someone please explain what is the difference between the `Imagick` class and `imagecopyresampled, imagecreatefromstring, imagecreatetruecolor, imagejpeg, imagepng`, and os on? I would be so glad to hear some information on this topic.  + Which one better or worse and what would you recommend (in what cases of use) any why. Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing. You're basically asking whether to use ImageMagick or GD. The difference is speed (GD) versus quality and versatility (ImageMagick). Generally speaking, the differences are: GD is generally a slight bit faster when dealing with large images. ImageMagick supports a larger number of image formats. ImageMagick is usually better at producing higher quality images (although sometimes at the expense of file size).

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319203/imagemagick-vs-gd-which-is-faster-less-resource-intensive-and-produces-better

Answer (score 58):

Simply use PHP's GD functions (like **imagescale**):

**Syntax:**

```
imagescale ( $image , $new_width , $new_height )
```

**Example:**

Step: 1 Read the file

```
$image_name =  'path_of_Image/Name_of_Image.jpg|png|gif';
```

Step: 2: Load the Image File

```
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_name); // For JPEG
//or
 $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_name);   // For PNG
 //or
 $image = imagecreatefromgif($image_name);   // For GIF
```

Step: 3: Our Life-saver comes in '_' | Scale the image

```
   $imgResized = imagescale($image , 500, 400); // width=500 and height = 400
//  $imgResized is our final product
```

Note: imagescale will work for (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)

Step: 4: Save the Resized image to your desired directory.

```
imagejpeg($imgResized, 'path_of_Image/Name_of_Image_resized.jpg'); //for jpeg
imagepng($imgResized, 'path_of_Image/Name_of_Image_resized.png'); //for png
```

Source : [Click to Read more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php)

Comment: Best solution for PHP 5.6.3 >

Answer (score 29):

<s>[This resource](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/)</s>(broken link) is also worth considering - some very tidy code that uses GD. However, I modified their final code snippet to create this function which meets the OPs requirements...

```
function store_uploaded_image($html_element_name, $new_img_width, $new_img_height) {
    
    $target_dir = "your-uploaded-images-folder/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES[$html_element_name]["name"]);
    
    $image = new SimpleImage();
    $image->load($_FILES[$html_element_name]['tmp_name']);
    $image->resize($new_img_width, $new_img_height);
    $image->save($target_file);
    return $target_file; //return name of saved file in case you want to store it in you database or show confirmation message to user
    
}
```

You will also need to include this PHP file...

```
<?php
 
/*
* File: SimpleImage.php
* Author: Simon Jarvis
* Copyright: 2006 Simon Jarvis
* Date: 08/11/06
* Link: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/
*
* This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
* modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
* as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
* of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
* GNU General Public License for more details:
* http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*
*/
 
class SimpleImage {
 
   var $image;
   var $image_type;
 
   function load($filename) {
 
      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
 
         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
 
         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
 
         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {
 
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
 
         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
 
         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {
 
         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
 
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
 
         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
 
         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
   function getWidth() {
 
      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {
 
      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {
 
      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
 
   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
 
   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
 
   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }      
 
}
?>
```

Comment: Your sample is the best. it works in Zend framework directly without making comedy, drama, hair pulling. thumbs up

Comment: I think all the code you need should be in my answer, but this may also help: https://gist.github.com/arrowmedia/7863973 .

Comment: This works great! Only one issue, on pictures taken from smartphones, it does not preserve the original rotatio of the image, is there a way around it?

Answer (score 15):

If you dont care about the aspect ration (i.e you want to force the image to a particular dimension), here is a simplified answer

```
// for jpg 
function resize_imagejpg($file, $w, $h) {
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
   $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
   $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
   imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
   return $dst;
}

 // for png
function resize_imagepng($file, $w, $h) {
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
   $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
   $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
   imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
   return $dst;
}

// for gif
function resize_imagegif($file, $w, $h) {
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
   $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
   $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
   imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
   return $dst;
}
```

Now let's handle the upload part.
First step, upload the file to your desired directory. Then called one of the above functions based on file type (jpg, png or gif) and pass the absolute path of your uploaded file as below:

```
 // jpg  change the dimension 750, 450 to your desired values
 $img = resize_imagejpg('path/image.jpg', 750, 450);
```

The return value `$img` is a resource object. We can save to a new location or override the original as below:

```
 // again for jpg
 imagejpeg($img, 'path/newimage.jpg');
```

Hope this helps someone. Check these links for more on resizing  [Imagick::resizeImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php) and
[imagejpeg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Comment: without changing the `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`,firstly  you cannot upload the file of size more than `upload_max_filesize`. Is there any chance to resize the image of size more than `upload_max_filesize` without changing `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 10):

(**IMPORTANT**: In the case of animation (animated webp or gif) resizing, the result will be a not animated, but resized image from the first frame! (The original animation remains intact...)

I created this to my **php 7.2** project (example imagebmp sure (PHP 7 >= 7.2.0) :[php/manual/function.imagebmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagebmp.php)) about [techfry.com/php-tutorial](https://www.techfry.com/php-tutorial), with GD2, (so nothing 3rd party library) and very similar to the answer of Nico Bistolfi, but works with the all five basic image mimetype (**png, jpeg, webp, bmp and gif**), creating a new resized file, without modifying the original one, and the all stuff in one function and ready to use (copy and paste to your project). (You can set the extension of the new file with the fifth parameter, or just leave it, if you want keep the orignal):

```
function createResizedImage(
    string $imagePath = '',
    string $newPath = '',
    int $newWidth = 0,
    int $newHeight = 0,
    string $outExt = 'DEFAULT'
) : ?string
{
    if (!$newPath or !file_exists ($imagePath)) {
        return null;
    }

    $types = [IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_BMP, IMAGETYPE_WEBP];
    $type = exif_imagetype ($imagePath);

    if (!in_array ($type, $types)) {
        return null;
    }

    list ($width, $height) = getimagesize ($imagePath);

    $outBool = in_array ($outExt, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'webp']);

    switch ($type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg ($imagePath);
            if (!$outBool) $outExt = 'jpg';
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $image = imagecreatefrompng ($imagePath);
            if (!$outBool) $outExt = 'png';
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $image = imagecreatefromgif ($imagePath);
            if (!$outBool) $outExt = 'gif';
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_BMP:
            $image = imagecreatefrombmp ($imagePath);
            if (!$outBool) $outExt = 'bmp';
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_WEBP:
            $image = imagecreatefromwebp ($imagePath);
            if (!$outBool) $outExt = 'webp';
    }

    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor ($newWidth, $newHeight);

    //TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha ($newImage, 0, 0, 0, 127); //fill transparent back
    imagefill ($newImage, 0, 0, $color);
    imagesavealpha ($newImage, true);

    //ROUTINE
    imagecopyresampled ($newImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

    // Rotate image on iOS
    if(function_exists('exif_read_data') && $exif = exif_read_data($imagePath, 'IFD0'))
    {
        if(isset($exif['Orientation']) && isset($exif['Make']) && !empty($exif['Orientation']) && preg_match('/(apple|ios|iphone)/i', $exif['Make'])) {
            switch($exif['Orientation']) {
                case 8:
                    if ($width > $height) $newImage = imagerotate($newImage,90,0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $newImage = imagerotate($newImage,180,0);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $newImage = imagerotate($newImage,-90,0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    switch (true) {
        case in_array ($outExt, ['jpg', 'jpeg']): $success = imagejpeg ($newImage, $newPath);
            break;
        case $outExt === 'png': $success = imagepng ($newImage, $newPath);
            break;
        case $outExt === 'gif': $success = imagegif ($newImage, $newPath);
            break;
        case  $outExt === 'bmp': $success = imagebmp ($newImage, $newPath);
            break;
        case  $outExt === 'webp': $success = imagewebp ($newImage, $newPath);
    }

    if (!$success) {
        return null;
    }

    return $newPath;
}
```

Comment: You are great! This is simple and clean solution. I had issue with Imagick module and solve problems with this simple class. Thanks!

Comment: Great, If you want I can add another update later, I improve this a bit.

Comment: sure! I still haven't got time to build the animation resizing part ...

Comment: @danigore, how to resize raw images (`.cr2, .dng, .nef` and the likes)?  GD2 doesn't have any support and after lot of struggle, i was able to setup ImageMagick.  But, it fails with connection time out error while reading the file.  And, no error log either..

Comment: @danigore I add to your function automatic image rotation to fix Apple problems.

Comment: I use this solution for `how to make image background Transparent` .. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I hope is will work for you.

```
/**
         * Image re-size
         * @param int $width
         * @param int $height
         */
        function ImageResize($width, $height, $img_name)
        {
                /* Get original file size */
                list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['logo_image']['tmp_name']);


                /*$ratio = $w / $h;
                $size = $width;

                $width = $height = min($size, max($w, $h));

                if ($ratio < 1) {
                    $width = $height * $ratio;
                } else {
                    $height = $width / $ratio;
                }*/

                /* Calculate new image size */
                $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
                $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
                $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
                $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
                /* set new file name */
                $path = $img_name;


                /* Save image */
                if($_FILES['logo_image']['type']=='image/jpeg')
                {
                    /* Get binary data from image */
                    $imgString = file_get_contents($_FILES['logo_image']['tmp_name']);
                    /* create image from string */
                    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
                    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image, 0, 0, $x, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h);
                    imagejpeg($tmp, $path, 100);
                }
                else if($_FILES['logo_image']['type']=='image/png')
                {
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['logo_image']['tmp_name']);
                    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
                    imagealphablending($tmp, false);
                    imagesavealpha($tmp, true);
                    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,0,0,$x,0,$width,$height,$w, $h);
                    imagepng($tmp, $path, 0);
                }
                else if($_FILES['logo_image']['type']=='image/gif')
                {
                    $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['logo_image']['tmp_name']);

                    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
                    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($tmp, 0, 0, 0, 127);
                    imagefill($tmp, 0, 0, $transparent);
                    imagealphablending($tmp, true); 

                    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$w, $h);
                    imagegif($tmp, $path);
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
                imagedestroy($image);
                imagedestroy($tmp);
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

I created an easy-to-use library for image resizing. It can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/Oberto/php-image-magician).

An example of how to use the library:

```
// Include PHP Image Magician library
require_once('php_image_magician.php');

// Open JPG image
$magicianObj = new imageLib('racecar.jpg');

// Resize to best fit then crop (check out the other options)
$magicianObj -> resizeImage(100, 200, 'crop');

// Save resized image as a PNG (or jpg, bmp, etc)
$magicianObj -> saveImage('racecar_small.png');
```

Other features, should you need them, are:

- Quick and easy resize - Resize to landscape, portrait, or auto
- Easy crop
- Add text
- Quality adjustment
- Watermarking
- Shadows and reflections
- Transparency support
- Read EXIF metadata
- Borders, Rounded corners, Rotation
- Filters and effects
- Image sharpening
- Image type conversion
- BMP support

Comment: This saved my day.
However, there's a small notice I've to someone who was searching for 3 days like me and was about to lose hope for finding any resizing solution.
If you see undefined index notices in the future, just see this link : https://github.com/Oberto/php-image-magician/pull/16/commits
And apply the changes to the files.
It'll work 100% without any problems.

Comment: Hey, @Hema_Elmasry. FYI,  I've just merged those changes into the main :)

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't notice.
But I've a question.
When I do a resize to a smaller resolution with quality not changed, the displayed image quality be much lower.
Has something similar happened to you before ?
Because I still didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I found a mathematical way to get this job done

Github repo - https://github.com/gayanSandamal/easy-php-image-resizer

Live example - https://plugins.nayague.com/easy-php-image-resizer/

```
<?php
//path for the image
$source_url = '2018-04-01-1522613288.PNG';

//separate the file name and the extention
$source_url_parts = pathinfo($source_url);
$filename = $source_url_parts['filename'];
$extension = $source_url_parts['extension'];

//define the quality from 1 to 100
$quality = 10;

//detect the width and the height of original image
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source_url);
$width;
$height;

//define any width that you want as the output. mine is 200px.
$after_width = 200;

//resize only when the original image is larger than expected with.
//this helps you to avoid from unwanted resizing.
if ($width > $after_width) {

    //get the reduced width
    $reduced_width = ($width - $after_width);
    //now convert the reduced width to a percentage and round it to 2 decimal places
    $reduced_radio = round(($reduced_width / $width) * 100, 2);

    //ALL GOOD! let's reduce the same percentage from the height and round it to 2 decimal places
    $reduced_height = round(($height / 100) * $reduced_radio, 2);
    //reduce the calculated height from the original height
    $after_height = $height - $reduced_height;

    //Now detect the file extension
    //if the file extension is 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'JPG' or 'JPEG'
    if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'JPG' || $extension == 'JPEG') {
        //then return the image as a jpeg image for the next step
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    } elseif ($extension == 'png' || $extension == 'PNG') {
        //then return the image as a png image for the next step
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
    } else {
        //show an error message if the file extension is not available
        echo 'image extension is not supporting';
    }

    //HERE YOU GO :)
    //Let's do the resize thing
    //imagescale([returned image], [width of the resized image], [height of the resized image], [quality of the resized image]);
    $imgResized = imagescale($img, $after_width, $after_height, $quality);

    //now save the resized image with a suffix called "-resized" and with its extension. 
    imagejpeg($imgResized, $filename . '-resized.'.$extension);

    //Finally frees any memory associated with image
    //**NOTE THAT THIS WONT DELETE THE IMAGE
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($imgResized);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extended version of the answer @Ian Atkin' gave. I found it worked extremely well. For larger images that is :). You can actually make smaller images larger if you're not careful. 
Changes: 
- Supports jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp files
- Preserves transparency for .png and .gif
- Double checks if the the size of the original isnt already smaller
- Overrides the image given directly (Its what I needed)

So here it is. The default values of the function are the "golden rule"

```
function resize_image($file, $w = 1200, $h = 741, $crop = false)
   {
       try {
           $ext = pathinfo(storage_path() . $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
           list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
           // if the image is smaller we dont resize
           if ($w > $width && $h > $height) {
               return true;
           }
           $r = $width / $height;
           if ($crop) {
               if ($width > $height) {
                   $width = ceil($width - ($width * abs($r - $w / $h)));
               } else {
                   $height = ceil($height - ($height * abs($r - $w / $h)));
               }
               $newwidth = $w;
               $newheight = $h;
           } else {
               if ($w / $h > $r) {
                   $newwidth = $h * $r;
                   $newheight = $h;
               } else {
                   $newheight = $w / $r;
                   $newwidth = $w;
               }
           }
           $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

           switch ($ext) {
               case 'jpg':
               case 'jpeg':
                   $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                   break;
               case 'png':
                   $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                   imagecolortransparent($dst, imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 0, 0, 0, 127));
                   imagealphablending($dst, false);
                   imagesavealpha($dst, true);
                   break;
               case 'gif':
                   $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                   imagecolortransparent($dst, imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 0, 0, 0, 127));
                   imagealphablending($dst, false);
                   imagesavealpha($dst, true);
                   break;
               case 'bmp':
                   $src = imagecreatefrombmp($file);
                   break;
               default:
                   throw new Exception('Unsupported image extension found: ' . $ext);
                   break;
           }
           $result = imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
           switch ($ext) {
               case 'bmp':
                   imagewbmp($dst, $file);
                   break;
               case 'gif':
                   imagegif($dst, $file);
                   break;
               case 'jpg':
               case 'jpeg':
                   imagejpeg($dst, $file);
                   break;
               case 'png':
                   imagepng($dst, $file);
                   break;
           }
           return true;
       } catch (Exception $err) {
           // LOG THE ERROR HERE 
           return false;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Great function @DanielDoinov - thanks for posting it - quick question: is there a way to only pass the width and let the function relatively adjust the height based on the original image? In other words, if the original is 400x200, can we tell the function we want the new width to be 200 and let the function figure out that the height should be 100?

Comment: Regarding your conditional expression, I don't think it makes sense to execute the resizing technique if `$w === $width && $h === $height`.  Think about it.  Should be `>=` and `>=` comparisons. @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

ZF cake:

```
<?php

class FkuController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

  var $image;
  var $image_type;

  public function store_uploaded_image($html_element_name, $new_img_width, $new_img_height) {

    $target_dir = APPLICATION_PATH  . "/../public/1/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES[$html_element_name]["name"]);

    //$image = new SimpleImage();
    $this->load($_FILES[$html_element_name]['tmp_name']);
    $this->resize($new_img_width, $new_img_height);
    $this->save($target_file);
    return $target_file; 
    //return name of saved file in case you want to store it in you database or show confirmation message to user



  public function load($filename) {

      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
  public function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {

         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
  public function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
  public function getWidth() {

      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
  public function getHeight() {

      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
  public function resizeToHeight($height) {

      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

  public function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

  public function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

  public function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }

  public function savepicAction() {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    $this->db = Application_Model_Db::db_load();        
    $ouser = $_POST['ousername'];


      $fdata = 'empty';
      if (isset($_FILES['picture']) && $_FILES['picture']['size'] > 0) {
        $file_size = $_FILES['picture']['size'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];  

        //Determine filetype
        switch ($_FILES['picture']['type']) {
            case 'image/jpeg': $ext = "jpg"; break;
            case 'image/png': $ext = "png"; break;
            case 'image/jpg': $ext = "jpg"; break;
            case 'image/bmp': $ext = "bmp"; break;
            case 'image/gif': $ext = "gif"; break;
            default: $ext = ''; break;
        }

        if($ext) {
          //if($file_size<400000) {  
            $img = $this->store_uploaded_image('picture', 90,82);
            //$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
            $fp = fopen($img, 'r');
            $fdata = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));        
            $fdata = base64_encode($fdata);
            fclose($fp);

          //}
        }

      }

      if($fdata=='empty'){

      }
      else {
        $this->db->update('users', 
          array(
            'picture' => $fdata,             
          ), 
          array('username=?' => $ouser ));        
      }



  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an easy way:

```
function resize($file, $width, $height) {
    switch(pathinfo($file)['extension']) {
        case "png": return imagepng(imagescale(imagecreatefrompng($file), $width, $height), $file);
        case "gif": return imagegif(imagescale(imagecreatefromgif($file), $width, $height), $file);
        default : return imagejpeg(imagescale(imagecreatefromjpeg($file), $width, $height), $file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private function getTempImage($url, $tempName){
  $tempPath = 'tempFilePath' . $tempName . '.png';
  $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($url); // check type depending on your necessities.
  $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
  $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
  $dest_imagex = 861; // My default value
  $dest_imagey = 96;  // My default value

  $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);

  imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);

  imagejpeg($dest_image, $tempPath, 100);

  return $tempPath;
```

}

This is an adapted solution based on [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/scaling-images-in-php-done-right) great explanation. This guy made a step by step explanation.
Hope all enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to TinyPNG PHP library. Using this library your image gets optimized automatically during resizing process. All you need to install the library and get an API key from https://tinypng.com/developers. To install a library, run the below command.

```
composer require tinify/tinify
```

After that, your code is as follows.

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

\Tinify\setKey("YOUR_API_KEY");

$source = \Tinify\fromFile("large.jpg"); //image to be resize
$resized = $source->resize(array(
    "method" => "fit",
    "width" => 150,
    "height" => 100
));
$resized->toFile("thumbnail.jpg"); //resized image
```

I have a written a blog on the same topic http://artisansweb.net/resize-image-php-using-tinypng