# How to re-size image and upload in different folder with different size?

Tags: php, image-resizing, image-upload, php-imagine

I am new in php. For my shopping website project I need your help.

In my add_product page I have product image option. When I submit the form the File image will re-size in 3 different size in different folder like-

```
30x30 for Shopping cart icon in 'Product/Image/Icon' folder.
170x300 for Base image in 'Product/Image/Base' folder.
400x300 for Large View in 'Product/Image/Thumb' folder.
```

I have also a database table -

```
ID
Product ID
thumb_name
thumb_type
```

After submit form also each file generate a unique new name and saved in the above table in like -

```
ID : Auto increment
Product ID : 44545
thumb_name : new file name here
thumb_type:  Base Image
```

How to re-size image and upload in different folder with different size and insert the file name in MySQL database? Plz help me any one.

Comment: You might want to split your question into two, to cover the "resize image" and the "inserting file name in MySQL". For the image resizing part, check [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resize image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After upload store only image base name to the database eg. product1.jpg
2. then create thumbs with same name in different directories..

   uploaded file - **uploads/product1.jpg**
       small thumb - **uploads/thumbs/small/product1.jpg**

here is a function to create thumb in php

```
function createThumb($filepath, $thumbPath, $maxwidth, $maxheight, $quality=75)
{   
            $created=false;
            $file_name  = pathinfo($filepath);  
            $format = $file_name['extension'];
            // Get new dimensions
            $newW   = $maxwidth;
            $newH   = $maxheight;

            // Resample
            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newW, $newH);
            $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filepath));
            list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filepath);
            imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newW, $newH, $width_orig, $height_orig);

            // Output
            switch (strtolower($format)) {
                case 'png':
                imagepng($thumb, $thumbPath, 9);
                $created=true;
                break;

                case 'gif':
                imagegif($thumb, $thumbPath);
                $created=true;
                break;

                default:
                imagejpeg($thumb, $thumbPath, $quality);
                $created=true;
                break;
            }
            imagedestroy($image);
            imagedestroy($thumb);
            return $created;    
}
```

parameter details

```
$filepath // uploaded file path include name eg. uploads/product1.jpg
$thumbPath // thumbpath with name eg. uploads/thumbs/small/product1.jpg
$maxwidth // width for the thumb eg. 100
$maxheight// height for the thumb eg. 60
$quality=75 // quality for the thumb image 1 - 100 ...by default it is 75
```