# Imagescale Function in PHP

Tags: php, gd

we use the imagescale() function in php 5.5.0. But now i am using the php version 5.3.29 and imagescale() function is not working in this version. so please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [resize image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

`imagescale` function was introduced in `PHP5.5` you cant use however there is a very good extention in PHP i.e `Imagick` for processing images you must use that

`http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php`

Answer (score 0):

There is also the gd package. It is usually bundled with PHP and has the function [imagecopyresized()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecopyresized.php)