# PHP resize HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA to save image

Tags: php

How do I get a HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and can resize to create a smaller image. With the image saved to disk I have classes that does this, more to get HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA I do not know how to do

```
    if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) 
{
    //the image file name   
    $fileName =  $_GET['nome'].".jpg";

    // get the binary stream
    $im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

    //write it
    $fp = fopen('saves/print/'.$fileName, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $im);
    fclose($fp);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resize image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If the image is coming from a multipart HTML form, then I don't think you can use the raw post data at all...I will likely be empty if I recall my attempts to read it previously.

Instead, you should use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Then, resize the image via ImageMagick or GD:

[resize image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)