# How to create a image resizer in PHP?

Tags: php, image-resizing

I want to resize image to a fixed dimension(say 180 X 180) .No matter what the size of user input image is,I want the resized one to be stored in database and retreived later.

Is there any library/function available in PHP for the same ?

Comment: Try ImageMagick (server based tool)

Comment: What have you tried until now ? Could you please join your attempts ? [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resize image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into [Intervention image](http://image.intervention.io) if you don't wanna write anything yourself. It can use both GD or ImageMagick and has many built in functions that allow solving most of the trivial image problems with several lines of code.

As simple as that:

```
$img = Image::make('yourimage.jpg')
$img->resize(180, 180);
```

And then use either `save` or `encode` method based on your needs.