# PHP/Shellscript - How to crop and resize many photos programmatically?

Tags: php, linux, shell, image-processing, imagemagick-convert

I want to crop and resize about 200,000 personnel photos to use in a organization website. I need 5 different sizes for each photo.

I have resized them using `convert` command in Linux but the problem is they don't have expected dimensions because the original photos have different dimensions. So I need to crop them. But is there a safe way to be sure full face is in cropped images?

p.s: I can use PHP/shellscript if is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resize image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

Comment: I believe it might be possible with [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html), if your question is to programmatically detect face boundaries. If photos are uniformed enough, it may be simpler to spot a pattern, crop, visually filter out the good ones, adjust parameters and apply for the rest, repeating it several times.