# How to upload an image with CKEditor in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ckeditor, image-uploading

Currently I am using [`angular-ckeditor`](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor) to add **CKEditor 4**.

In my template, I display it as:

```
<div ng-repeat="editor in editors">
  <div ckeditor="options" ng-model="editor.content"></div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to **upload images to CKEditor from desktop**. As far as I understand, `angular-ckeditor` and `CKEditor` libraries are separate, so I can add widgets and plugins easily.

The problem is that I can't seem to find the right plugins/widgets (*that do NOT use jQuery*), which will help me to upload an image from desktop. I made it work only with image links.

There is not a lot of documentation about it on the official website. They say to use PHP files that will upload and *browse* images, but don't really explain how, especially with `angular-ckeditor`. So I have several questions now:

- Which plugins do I need for a simple image uploader, so that I can paste images into CKEditor?
- How do I set it up with AngularJS?
- What does a PHP file uploader(/browser) look like?

What I have tried so far doesn't even change the CKEditor tabs (it *should* change the image properties dialog by adding an "Upload" tab and some other UI). So clearly I'm missing a solid tutorial somewhere for all of this.

[image]

(*I could also try to switch to* `ng-ckeditor`*, if a solution with this would be simpler*)

Comment: Is it version 5?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash CKEditor version 4, AngularJS 1.6.X~

Comment: Did you have a chance to try [`uploadimage` CKEditor plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/uploadimage) (just make sure you've downloaded all the required dependencies if you are not using [builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder) to create your CKEditor build, for me it was like `button`, `filetools`, `notification`, `notificationaggregator`, `toolbar`, `uploadwidget`, `widget`)?

Comment: After adding this plugin just add it through the options like `extraPlugins: 'uploadimage', filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'fileUploadUrl`. Your back-end should return a JSON response, examples are shown here: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_file_upload

Comment: Just realized that JSON responses would not work with `uploadimage` (it expects plain html since it just inserts this html into result window - see `imageUpload.html` file), so the setup could look like https://plnkr.co/edit/0JQD4dznMP6do2LTBhn2

Comment: @StanislavKvitash I think at some point one of the dependencies requires jQuery. Can I set it up without it? Or is it 100% needed? (That plunker looks promising, I will try it with my backend)

Comment: You should be good to use it without jQuery (I removed jQuery from that plunker and it could be fully functional, if I know how to "simulate" post request to `imageUpload.html` in `plnkr` :) ). Just give it a try and share your results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's take a look at some basics without Angular. For CKEditor version 4, we can initialize an editor with the `filebrowserImageUploadUrl` configuration option, which enables functionality from the [File Browser API](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api):

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', { 
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/upload.php?type=image' 
});
```

This just loads an editor instance onto a `<textarea name="editor">`. Because we set the `filebrowserImageUploadUrl` option, the *Upload* tab becomes available in the editor's image dialog. The example value, `/upload.php?type=image`, is the URL to the PHP script on the server that handles the uploaded image files.

When a user uploads an image, CKEditor will send the image to this URL on the server. The handler at this URL should validate the request, resize the image (if needed), and move the uploaded image to a permanent location on the server. Then, the handler sends an HTML response back to CKEditor with the image's public URL.

Of course, we can write the server-side handler in any language. Here's a basic example for PHP that we'll save as *upload.php*:

```
<?php 
$tempName = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = uniqid() . $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$uploadPath = '/path/to/uploads/' . $fileName;
$imageUrl = 'http://example.com/uploads/' . $fileName;

$success = move_uploaded_file($tempName, $uploadPath);

$html = '<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(%s, "%s", "%s");</script>';
$message = $success ? 'Uploaded successfully.' : 'Upload failed.';
echo sprintf($html, $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'], $imageUrl, $message);
```

This script places an uploaded image into the web server's *uploads/* directory so the browser can fetch the image. It passes back the `CKEditorFuncNum` parameter from the request to identify the appropriate callback for the upload. This example provides some *basic* protection against duplicate filenames, but, for a real-world application, we'd need to add security, validation, and error handling (authentication, CSRF, file type checking, max size, file name sanitization, etc.).

---

So far, this all works with CKEditor's standard, built-in functionality (no plugins, Angular, or jQuery needed). To enable users to drag-and-drop or paste images into the editor, we can add the [Upload Image plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/uploadimage) to our CKEditor build (or use the *standard-all* distribution from the [CKEditor CDN](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/)).

We need to declare the plugin when initializing the editor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', { 
    extraPlugins: 'uploadimage',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/upload.php?type=image' 
});
```

...and then extend our *upload.php* script to return the JSON response expected by the plugin. Add this block *before* the last three lines of the previous example:

```
if (isset($_GET['responseType']) && $_GET['responseType'] === 'json') {
    echo json_encode([
        'uploaded' => $success,
        'fileName' => $fileName,
        'url' => $imageUrl,
    ]);

    return;
}
```

The Upload Image plugin sends the `responseType=json` URL parameter that the server-side script can check for to determine which type of response to send back.

---

Finally, let's take a look at how to initialize an editor using the [angular-ckeditor](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor) package described in the question:

```
<div ng-controller="EditorCtrl as editor">
    <textarea ckeditor="editor.options" ng-model="editor.content"></textarea>
</div>
```

```javascript
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ckeditor'])

myApp.controller('EditorCtrl', function () {
    this.options = {
        extraPlugins: 'uploadimage',
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/image-upload.php?type=image'
    };
});
```

As we can see, we don't need to do much to "angularize" this. Once we create our template, we declare the *same* configuration options that we'd pass to the plain `CKEDITOR.replace()` on a controller that we reference on an element with the `ckeditor` directive.

Comment: Works great. (just to confirm) **1.** Does `$imageUrl` have to be a url link? I made it work with a root directory. **2.** I would like to know what a string X stands for in `$_FILES[X]['tmp_name']`. And for that, how do I _echo_ anything out for testing purposes? **3.** Can an image be resized? Do I need a plugin for that and do I change anything in `upload.php`?

Comment: @Aleksey **1.** No, it does not. The full URL is just an example. Just passing a path component should work as long as the front end loads from the same domain as the server. **2.** *`X`* is the "name" attribute of the hidden file input field that CKEditor uses to upload the image (`<input name="upload" type="file">`). **2.5** `error_log()` will write a value to the server's log (depends on webserver). Also, try `var_dump()` and look in the browser's devtools. **3.** See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14649645/5209322). You can do this in *upload.php* before moving the temp image.