# Resize images inside slides with PHPPowerPoint

Tags: php, phppowerpoint

I'm using the PHPPowerPoint lib to generate some powerpoint files. The problem is that the images that are coming from the server are too big, and are breaking the limits of the slide. 
Here is some code that I'm using for the images:

```
if(file_exists($dir.$image)){
    // Add logo
    $shape = $slide->createDrawingShape();
    $shape->setName('PHPPowerPoint logo');
    $shape->setDescription('PHPPowerPoint logo');
    $shape->setPath($dir.$image);
    $shape->setWidth(310);
    $shape->setHeight(608);
    $shape->setOffsetX(330);  
    $shape->setOffsetY(70); 
    //$shape->setOffsetY(720 - 10 - 40);
    }
```

Notice that Im already setting the width and height, but the image is not respecting those configurations. Is there anything that I can do to make the images respect the size that I need or get a responsive behavior?

**Edit**:
This the code for the function createTemplateSlide:

```
function createTemplatedSlide(PHPPowerPoint $objPHPPowerPoint, $dir, $image, $razao, $nome, $data, $contador)
{
    // Create slide
    $slide = $objPHPPowerPoint->createSlide();

    if(file_exists($dir.$image)){
    // echo("$contador) o arquivo: '".$dir.$image."' existe <br>");
    // Add logo
    $shape = $slide->createDrawingShape();
    $shape->setName('PHPPowerPoint logo');
    $shape->setDescription('PHPPowerPoint logo');
    $shape->setPath($dir.$image);
    $shape->setWidth(310);
    $shape->setHeight(608);
    $shape->setOffsetX(330);  
    $shape->setOffsetY(70); 
    //$shape->setOffsetY(720 - 10 - 40);
    }

    // Create a shape (text)
    // echo date('H:i:s') . " Create a shape (rich text)<br>";
    $shape = $slide->createRichTextShape();
    $shape->setHeight(60);
    $shape->setWidth(960);
    $shape->setOffsetX(0);
    $shape->setOffsetY(20);
    $shape->getAlignment()->setHorizontal( PHPPowerPoint_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER );

    $textRun = $shape->createTextRun($razao."  ".$data);
    $textRun->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $textRun->getFont()->setSize(16);
    $textRun->getFont()->setColor( new PHPPowerPoint_Style_Color( '00000000' ) );

    for ($i=0; $i <23 ; $i++) { 
        $shape->createBreak();
    }

    $textRun = $shape->createTextRun(utf8_encode($nome));
    $textRun->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $textRun->getFont()->setSize(16);
    $textRun->getFont()->setColor( new PHPPowerPoint_Style_Color( '00000000' ) );


    // Return slide
    return $slide;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the createDrawingShape() function?

Comment: Hard to fix anything with the code we have. im guessing this is a class.

Comment: How do you tell your function the units used? Cuse you could give a % value or a pixel value?

Comment: I added the code for the createTemplateSlide function. About the correct size, Im not sure what width and height I should use, but what I want is that the image stays centered and inside the limits of the slide.

Comment: @MadeInDreams createDrawingShape() is a function of the phppowerpoint lib.

Comment: everything is working beside that?

Comment: Yes @MadeInDreams the ppt files is generated normally, everything is ok. I only need the image smaller, inside the slide. I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: In de doc http://phppresentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#basic-example. They are using only the height. Have you tryed that?

Comment: @MadeInDreams, I'm setting the height and width like this: 
`$shape->setHeight(60);
$shape->setWidth(310);
`
It doesn't work.

Comment: Use $gdImage = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
http://phppresentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shapes_drawing.html

Comment: Ok @MadeInDreams, I'm gonna try using this.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion given by @MadeInDreams, I found this topic:

[Resize image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

I used the solution there and the function **imagejpeg** to copy the new generated image to some folder of my project.