# How to read an image in the post and resize it and save it to server in PHP?

Tags: php, image

How can this be accomplished? The customer requires to take a picture in the post of the page, then to resize and store it to server. All using PHP and JSON.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or nothing at all? :|

Comment: [Imagick is a native php extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Comment: You say it's native, but do I need to install a dll?

Comment: This package:
[intervention/image](https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image)

Comment: I find extremely complicated to setup the imagemagick api and to extract the imagemagick archives. I would need a step by step from someone that has already done that. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well you can check the file size from using $_FILES

```
[file] => Array
    (
        [name] => MyFile.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
        [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
        [size] => 98174
    )
```

and regarding image resize you can refer "[Resize image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)"

Comment: till now I wrote this:
<?php

class Negozio {
       public $Articolo = $_POST["name"];
       public $Prezzo  = $_POST["price"];
       public $Img = $_POST["img"];
   }
 
   $e = new Negozio();
   

   echo json_encode($e);
?>

Comment: I will lookat your link