# resize or crop base64 images using php

Tags: php

I'm uploading images from the pc to a server using this php code

```
  $ImageToLoad=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image_attached']);

if($ImageToLoad){

$token=$token;//variable
$ImageToLoad = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $ImageToLoad);
$ImageToLoad = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $ImageToLoad);
$ImageToLoad = str_replace(' ', '+', $ImageToLoad);
$fileData = base64_decode($ImageToLoad);    


$destino_path="/images/$token/image.png";

file_put_contents($destino_path, $fileData);

}
```

It works ok.

**PROBLEM**

I need to know how to resize it/crop them before to store the image in the server. Otherwise it keeps the same size (problem when huge image)

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php

Comment: its actually not. this is not a file, is a bas64 image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to create a temp image from an image file for resizing, we can use

```
imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

or

```
imagecreatefrompng($filename);
```

If we want to create a temp image from blob we can use

```
imagecreatefromstring($blob);
```

[imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

So, give this a try:

```
<?php
$filename = 'folder_name/resized_image.png'; // output file name

$im = imagecreatefromstring($fileData);
$source_width = imagesx($im);
$source_height = imagesy($im);
$ratio =  $source_height / $source_width;

$new_width = 300; // assign new width to new resized image
$new_height = $ratio * 300;

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($thumb, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $transparency);

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $source_width, $source_height);
imagepng($thumb, $filename, 9);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for....but once created how do I upload it to the server? I think I wont be able to use `file_put_contents($destino_path, $fileData);` anymore1

Comment: simply change your output name.. $filename = "$desintao_path";

Answer (score 8):

Resizing images <strike>can be</strike> is a costly operation and should be handled by a specialized library. In the past, the default pointer was ImageMagick's [Imagick::resizeImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php). However, this package does not work for everybody and other solutions have emerged in the meantime.

I suggest gumlet's [php-image-resize](https://github.com/gumlet/php-image-resize). Resizing a base64 encoded image can be as simple as that:

```
$image = ImageResize::createFromString(base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAQCBP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=='));
$image->scale(50);
$image->save('image.jpg');
```

Comment: OK...I see the point. but I dont actually use libraries...do I need to install it on the  server?

Comment: It's not that hard. Just use composer, if available, or put the lib source files on the server and include `'/path/to/ImageResize.php';`

Comment: Note that gumlet uses a namespace. So it would look like: `\Gumlet\ImageResize::createFromString(....)`