# How to auto resize images in PHP?

Tags: php, ads, image-resizing, pagespeed, image-compression

I'm new to PHP. I start a website with free ads and what I need is when someone is posting a new ad, all the pictures to be automatically compressed or resized to use less space and to not affect my page load, my website is on PHP, how can I do this? with a script or a PHP code? I find here the code below, will be good? How can I use it?

```css
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 AddType image/x-icon .ico
 ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

```html
<img src="{{ image.thumb(200, 200, {mode:'auto',quality:85}) }}" title="{{ image.title }}" alt="{{ image.description }}">
```

[my website](https://onads.net)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14649645/3415984)

Comment: The `img` tag appears to have some sort of templating going on - fine if your site employs that technique but otherwise of no use.

Comment: @RamRaider: I imagine it is a feature in the Blade templating format.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to let people upload high resolution images, and then run a scheduled process (Cron) that reduces the file size of images whenever it finds a large one. I would say that your first task is to write some PHP code to do the image resizing.

Comment: @halfer - indeed it probably is ~ my concern was that the OP doesn't use such a system and thus it is of no practical use to them

Comment: Good spot RamRaider. It looks like @MadhuriPatel edited the title to mention Laravel, but it is not clear that Laravel is in use.

Comment: I have a pretty decent image class that will do the horsework for you https://github.com/delboy1978uk/image