# Cannot convert canvas.toDataURL('image/png') to an image with base64_decode

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to save an image to a folder in PHP by decoding a `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` coded image. The toDataURL gives me the following string:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAXYAAAF1CAYAAAD8ysHLAAAgAElEQVR4XuydCbiOVff/lw...
```

which is around 43 000 characters long. I send this to PHP via AJAX. Then I tried to follow some answers online how to decode it but none worked as expected. The one that came up the most is the following approach:

```
$img64String = $_POST['file'];
$img64String = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img64String);
$img64String = str_replace(' ', '+', $img64String);
$fileData = base64_decode($img64String);
```

Line 1 gets the original string, line 2 and 3 is to remove the first part and keep everything after the comma and then replace empty places with + according to documentation. However, the 4th line gives me a result which looks something like this:

```
FileData: �PNG IHDRvu���� IDATx^�    ��U���eʔ!    !
%��Pр$C*�FC��FD��&�(RRƷdJ�䯼Pʔyʐ�����?�s�9g�������ֺ.W�s�}��| 
��߽�����8�?&fF�#�@��5si�#�dka�����f�i�? 
���d�1'ݔ'�#�k���Ʉ]7��V&�...
```

Basically a string with a bunch of nonsense (?) in it. What is going on?

If there is of any help, here is the AJAX call:

```
form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('file', newImage);
            form_data.append('action', 'file_upload');
            form_data.append('security', blog.security);

            // Send to AJAX
            $.ajax({
                url: blog.ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data, ...
```

**What I want**

Previously I sent the uploaded file itself but now I want to resize it first, hence I used the new approach. Previously I used this on PHP side which works fine:

```
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$allowed_file_types = array('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg');
if (in_array($file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {
    $upload = wp_upload_bits($file_name, null, file_get_contents($file_temp_name));
    $status = "ok";
}
```

I want to get my string into something that I can use in a similar way if possible.

Comment: As hinted by the argument you're providing, `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` encodes the canvas image data as a PNG image, and then base64 encodes it. If you want access to the pixel data on the server, then after base64 decoding you'll need to decode the image.

Comment: @motto, I updated with what I want and what I used in the past. Do you know how to decode the image on server side?

Comment: There are a few options for [resizing an image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php) but `imagecreatefrompng` will get you some of the way :-)

Comment: @motto, no I don't want to resize in php, I have already resized in Javascript to send as little data as possible over AJAX. I just want to get the string from canvas.toDataURL('image/png') into something that I can use similarily to what I have at the end of my post

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread. Well, the good news is that it will actually be straightforward - you're currently using `file_get_contents($file_temp_name)` to get the encoded image contents, but now you already have the contents in `$fileData`.

Comment: @motto, changing "file_get_contents($file_temp_name)" to "$fileData" worked just like magic, thank you so much!! I will of course have to get file type and file name and send over ajax but that is no problem. Put this as an answer and I will accept :)